# issue with git ignore file inside war file

Tags: git, openshift

I'm uploading the war file to openshift. The question is if I put the git-ignore file inside the war file, will git ignore the files that I listed in git-ignore file ? Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, git will not ignore files specified in a .gitignore file inside of a war file.  How would git read the file?  If you want to use a .gitignore to exclude certain files you should use the default maven structure and let OpenShift build your project on the server and deploy it.